# What is the origin and purpose of the alms bowl used by monastics?

Tags: monasticism

How did this practice originate and what is the meaning/purpose for it's use?

Comment: The origin story can be found in the [mahavagga](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/vin/mv/mv01/mv.01.04.khem_en.html), where after the Buddha considered that receiving alms with hands isnt' prper for an Arahat the Gods gave him such to receive.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>*(Disclaimer: I'm going to answer this pragmatically and straightforwardly without any reference since I think it doesn't require any. There may be memorable stories about the bowl but I don't think they are really necessary to explain it. Feel free to discard the answer.)*</sup>

The alms-bowl serves the purpose of helping one carry the food & prevent spoiling it with external dirt. If you went on alms-round with your hands it wouldn't be helpful for yourself or for the lay people as it would create hygiene problems. It also helps one measure the amount of food to accept, whether it's only for himself or also for others with whom he shares the food.

<sub>(As the comments below show, the next paragraph is not applicable, since monks should hide their bowls under their robes until they know someone intends to give.)</sub>
Additionally, it helps other people identify readily what the person with the bowl wants, food. In other words, if one carries a bowl around, instead of a hat or any kind of cloth, it is more straightforward what he wants. If one carries a hat or any kind of cloth, it is easier to perceive that he wants money or something else apart from food.

As for it's origin, if I wanted food I would also use a bowl. Why would I use anything else? With this I mean that the origin is not necessarily something special or traditional, it's just a pragmatic tool that anyone who wants food would use.

Comment: Just a note that Buddhist monks aren't supposed to show the bowl until they are aware of the desire to offer food.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thank you. Can you give a reference? If that is so, I wonder, how does the desire to offer food appear in people if the monk can't show his bowl or give any clue he wants food? If a monk is just standing there or passing by without showing the bowl, why would people even stop to talk if they have no reason to interact?

Comment: Cv VIII.5 'When food is being given to him, he should lift up his robe (Samghâti) with his left hand so as to disclose his bowl, take the bowl in both his hands, and receive the food into it.' The idea is to only take food from those looking to give, rather than hinting with the bowl.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If a monk is in the street standing, how does he know who's willing to give? I can only envision a passer-by asking out of curiosity why he is wearing robes and that leads the monk to disclose his livelihood. Is this how it goes?

Comment: You don't just stand by the side of the road, you walk through the streets, checking to see if anyone is offering food. It is a technically passive practice, otherwise it would involve greed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Standing or walking, the question still stands though, how does the monk know who's willing to give? I can only envision a passer-by asking out of curiosity why he is wearing robes and that leads the monk to disclose his livelihood. But in this case, since he is walking, the passer-by might not even ask since it seems the monk is going somewhere. On a side note, what do you mean by "technically"? Please don't take these questions the wrong way, I'm just trying to understand how the alms-round goes with a hidden bowl. Maybe this should be taken to the chat or elsewhere.

Comment: Well, practically most monks probably want food, so it's only technically passive, but the point is to allow for a non-greed based practice, so it must be technically passive. There are guidelines on stopping and waiting to see if someone is giving. See the cula-vagga: http://www.sacred-texts.com/bud/sbe20/sbe20083.htm

Comment: I still haven't found how the monk knows if someone wants to give food but I'll try and find it some other way. Thank you for the replies. I added a note above due to these comments. May you be well.

Answer (score 0):

**The Origin:**

As I know the origin goes, before the Buddha's enlightenment. According to the legend,
Siddhartha Gautama in seeking Enlightenment sat under the spreading bowers of a giant Nuga Tree lying close to the bank of river Neranjana. Then the daughter to the village chief name "Sujatha" offered a bowl filled with rice, thinking he was the divinity of the tree (You could read the full story [here](http://www.sundayobserver.lk/2001/pix/PrintPage.asp?REF=/2009/08/09/spe10.asp).

**Purpose:**

- Collect alms for one or more than one monk. For instance if another monk is too sick to go on alms rounds
- Server as a kind of suitcase, specially for the forest monks. They can keep all the robes inside the bowl and keep it away from the rain or the small animals(Insect, Mice)
- Very practical object a symbol